# Patriotism is to country as ________ is to Company

Tags: single-word-requests

Patriotism is to country as ________ is to Company.

As used in.

"As global corporate entities gain size and power patriotism is being replaced with _________________ as love and loyalty to a corporation becomes more important to the pursuit of life, liberty and happiness than love and loyalty to a specific country."

Comment: I don't think an exact word exists, but I would use "loyalist." But even "loyalism" has a bit of nationalist connotation. Edit: looking it up, I think "loyalism" and "loyalist" would work fine. "one who is or remains loyal especially to a political cause, party, government, or sovereign" -- A company is a "party."

Comment: I would use "loyalty".

Comment: Or possibly "patriotism is being replaced with corporate loyalty."

Comment: Seems a bit weak. a pacifist can be loyal but they would seldom be called patriots or to be displaying patriotism.

Comment: I think you'll have to use an adjective for context. A corporate loyalist seems to fit in my opinion.

Comment: "Corporate Loyalist" does give the right context and is a good suggestion. "As global corporate entities gain size and power the patriots of old are becoming _corporate loyalists_ as love and loyalty to a corporation becomes more important to the pursuit of life, liberty and happiness then love and loyalty to a specific country." Should work.

Comment: Do you mean [brand loyalty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brand_loyalty)? I guess it's not really clear to me what "love and loyalty to a corporation" means. Is it: buying the same brand? Working for the same company, even if you could get a better offer?

Comment: @Laurel The Movie "Rising Sun" comes to mind. An employee at the end of the movie basically sacrifices his career so that the companies reputation doesn't get damaged. He does it because he knows the company will employ him and eventually retire him though he will never again hold any authority. I think in the movie they even give the Japanese term for it but its been years since I saw it.

Comment: Suggestion:  Look at the definition of "patriotism" and try to come up with a parallel definition.

Comment: @David You should edit your question to make it clear which one you're talking about, otherwise this will get closed.

Comment: As to writing advice, I suggest rewriting the sentence to elimnate the pleonasm

Comment: I think you are confusing patriotism and nationalism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In its pure meaning, loyalist sounds good, but loyalist raises political meanings in history. Could fidelity work? It brings marriage to mind instead of country, and people talk about being married to one's job.

Comment: "corporate fidelity" sounds good. But in contemplating that "corporate feudalism" might work as well. The political overtones are fine its basically the point that the nature of these is in flux.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of the sentence I think "servitude" or "service" might work.  Otherwise, "Loyalty" fills in the blank, but might seem redundant when used twice in the sentence.